# How to install Tun driver in Android Version 6.01?

Tags: android, linux, android-ndk, iptables, tun

At present I have simple tunnel C program(simpletun.c) integrated with Android Application(JNI,NDK)

But to make this app to run: need to set up(preferably by program) Tun Interface ? (Its not happening)

Such code returing -1 ( :

```
int tun_alloc(char *dev, int flags) {

    struct ifreq ifr;
    int fd, err;
    char *clonedev = "/dev/tun";

    if( (fd = open(clonedev , O_RDWR)) < 0 ) {
        jni_printf("Opening /dev/net/tun fail");
        return fd;
    }

    memset(&ifr, 0, sizeof(ifr));

    ifr.ifr_flags = flags;

    if (*dev) {
        strncpy(ifr.ifr_name, dev, IFNAMSIZ);
    }

    if( (err = ioctl(fd, TUNSETIFF, (void *)&ifr)) < 0 ) {
        jni_printf("ioctl(TUNSETIFF) error");
        close(fd);
        return err;
    }

    strcpy(dev, ifr.ifr_name);

    return fd;
}
```

Additional information :

*Added ADB Shell Terminal View [image]
*Rooted android phone already , installed iptables on it via iptables android app (iptables 1.4.20)